# Can I receive an MMS via exacttarget and manipulate it as an object within my application?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I want to be able to send an SMS to a user via exacttarget api and have them respond with a picture message. How can I receive that picture message as an object in my application so that I can upload it to my desired location? In this case AWS S3 storage.

Thank you very much for your time. Please let me know if I am being unclear or if you need anything else from me.